# Not receiving all values sent by putextra()

Tags: android

I tried to send data from one activity to another. The problem is I am not receiving all the datas. Just 3 instead of 6.PS: I am new to android development

sending data from this

```
Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),PigeonInfo.class);

                    String n=p.getPigeonID();
                    String f=p.getFathersID();
                    String m=p.getMothersID();
                    String g=p.getGender();
                    String gr=p.getGroup();
                    String u=p.getPicURL();


                    i.putExtra("PID",n);
                    i.putExtra("FID",f);
                    i.putExtra("MID:",m);
                    i.putExtra("PGN:",g);
                    i.putExtra("PGR:",gr);
                    i.putExtra("PUR",u);
                    startActivity(i);
```

To this:

```
    Intent i=getIntent()
    e1.setText(i.getStringExtra("PID"));
    e2.setText(i.getStringExtra("PGR"));
    e3.setText(i.getStringExtra("PGN"));
    e4.setText(i.getStringExtra("FID"));
    e5.setText(i.getStringExtra("MID"));
    String url= i.getStringExtra("PUR");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these 3 lines you add an extra `:` to the end of the key:

```
                i.putExtra("MID:",m);
                i.putExtra("PGN:",g);
                i.putExtra("PGR:",gr);
```

But when you retrieve them from the intent, you don't have a `:` anymore in the key:

```
e5.setText(intent.getStringExtra("MID"));
```

So you can fix this by removing the extra `:` characters in your `putExtra(...)` calls. 
Having typo's in these keys is pretty commons. You can work around such issues by defining these keys in static fields, which you reference from both places:

```
class Keys {
    public static final String PIGEON_MID = "pigeon_mid"
}

...

intent.putExtra(Keys.PIGEON_MID, pigeon.getMid());

...

String mid = intent.getStringExtra(Keys.PIGEON_MID);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use getIntent() instant of intent for getting the intent value
`
    first Activity

```
Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),PigeonInfo.class);

                    String n=p.getPigeonID();
                    String f=p.getFathersID();
                    String m=p.getMothersID();
                    String g=p.getGender();
                    String gr=p.getGroup();
                    String u=p.getPicURL();


                    i.putExtra("PID",n);
                    i.putExtra("FID",f);
                    i.putExtra("MID:",m);
                    i.putExtra("PGN:",g);
                    i.putExtra("PGR:",gr);
                    i.putExtra("PUR",u);
                    startActivity(i);


Second activity

Intent inent = getIntent();

    e1.setText(intent.getStringExtra("PID"));
    e2.setText(intent.getStringExtra("PGR"));
    e3.setText(intent.getStringExtra("PGN"));
    e4.setText(intent.getStringExtra("FID"));
    e5.setText(intent.getStringExtra("MID"));


    String url= intent.getStringExtra("PUR");`
```